# Generate token for GCP Cloud Run endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, .net-core, token, google-iam

I have been searching for documentation on how to call GCP Cloud run endpoint with proper authentication via On Prem .NET Core application. I'm sure I need to authenticate first using IAM service. However, I'm not getting clear direction on how to Generate token from IAM service via .NET Core.

Consumer application is .NET Core and hosted on-premise. Any directions? I do see a lot of JAVA documentation but nothing for .NET Core.

My worry is on what on prem application needs to do for calling GCP cloud run end point.

Comment: Did you search for `Cloud Run Authorization`? There is a lot of documentation. Edit your post to clearly state what you need to do. If you are calling your Google Cloud Run service, what authorization did you configure?

Comment: @JohnHanley - Edited my question. I have not configured any authorization yet. I am looking out for correct approach to call GCP endpoint from on-prem .netcore application.